# Hide a Prepopulated email textfield

Tags: entities

I am trying to prepopulate the following fields on a commerce add-to-cart form and then hide the email field:

1. Recipient name: (textfield) = field_recipient_name
2. Recipient email: (email field) = field_recipient_email

So far i have been able to pre-populate these fields using views, panels, and [prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) modules. My challenge is this:

If the email field is already prepopulated with a value, hide this field from the user who intends to buy a gift for the recipient, otherwise the field should be exposed so that user can manually enter the email of the gift recipient. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the [Conditional Fields module](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) to check whether the field has a value (sort of a 'not empty' check).

Conditional Fields is described as follows:

*Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.*